# Image Processing use Python find black contour

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have a problem  Please help me if I have an image multi 16 in 1 image I wanna find black contour in an image just one show YES if find black contour What should I do? in Image Processing use Python!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Python Image Library can give RGB data of an image. You can get RGB data simply by using

```
 import Image
 pic  = Image.open('/path/to/file')
 rgbdata = pic.load()
 width, height = pic.size

 def identify_black():
     for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            if rgbdata[i,j] == (0,0,0):
                #print rgbdata[i,j]   
                print "Yes"
                return True
            break

identify_black()
```

You can view the data purely in terms of RGB values of ijth pixel in rgbdata[i,j]. width and height help you define the blocks.

RGB value for black is (0,0,0). So if in your image list, a block of pixels give you (0,0,0) you can use that i, j th number to find in which block you have black! In fact, you identify any color!

Hope this helps.

Comment: You have to be careful with the black lines separating the color blocks though!

Comment: You have to install PIL first. Follow the guidelines here for installing https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library/Getting_PIL

Comment: if i wanna check each block What should I do?

Comment: From the size you get width and height. You have 4 blocks in each row. So width/4 and height/4 is the size of each block. If there are total n pixels in the image. n/16 should be in each block. So if you want to check each block, total no. of points in comparison with black (0,0,0) or any other color should be roughly n/16. first try to print all the rgbdata points you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is thresholding, just set any non black pixel(0,0,0) to (255,255,255) and you will have all the contours in an image.